# Loop through array of function names and execute all of them in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop

I write a bash script and i have an array of function names with variable passed to them and i want to execute all of them in a loop.

but when i execute the bash script, i get this error:

> a: command not found

how can i do this?

my bash script is look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

functions_array=("test a" "test b" "testc")

test() {
        echo $1
}

testc() { echo "testc!"; }

for i in ${functions_array[@]}; do
        ${i}
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you didn't quote your variables. Therefore `test a` is split into two parts.

Try it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

functions_array=("test a" "test b" "testc")

test() {
        echo "$1"                          # quoting here and ...
}

testc() { echo "testc!"; }

for i in "${functions_array[@]}"; do       # also here
        ${i}
done
```

Comment: quotes is necessary just in for loop declaration.

Comment: Quotes are always a good idea. You can check your shell scripts here: https://www.shellcheck.net/ There it recommends the same.